# Shower spout has rotated screw

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

I have a shower spout that fell off, but I can’t reattach it because the set screw is rotated inside the spout. Any ideas on how I can move the screw into position so that I can tighten it?

[image: shower spout rotated set screw]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Something should turn or pull out so you can get at that screw.

Comment: looks like the screw head is stripped anyway best path is likely just buy a new one.  if you really want then you can use vice grip to turn screw which maybe allows you to spin it back to the cut away.

Comment: It seems to me that the screw head should be where teh notch is.  Are you able to rotate the assembly ?

Comment: What have you tried already? Channelock pliers would seem like an obvious choice…

Comment: If the screw is loose enough, then that entire metal-ish looking ring which the screw is threaded into looks like it would be able turn on the plastic pipe/shaft/thing it's mounted on - allowing you to reposition the screw back at the notch in the outer housing.

Comment: you can soak the head in vineagar or CLR for an hour or so to loosen the hard-water crud cementing the interfaces together.